# Using cv2.getGaborKernel for various rotations

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, gabor-filter

I designed an algorithm that applies the Gabor filter to an image.
All input variables work very well, only the parameter "theta" reaches its limits.
Is there a possibility to modify the Gabor filter in such a way that it is independent of the angle?

[image: reference.png] [image: reference_gabor.png]

```
import cv2

def deginrad(degree):
    import numpy as np

    radiant = 2*np.pi/360 * degree
    return radiant

#################################################################################
# cv2.getGaborKernel(ksize, sigma, theta, lambda, gamma, phi, ktype)
# ksize - size of gabor filter (n, n) --> line width of road markings in pixel
# sigma - standard deviation of the gaussian function
# theta - orientation of the normal to the parallel stripes
# lambda - wavelength of the sunusoidal factor
# gamma - spatial aspect ratio
# phi - phase offset
# ktype - type and range of values that each pixel in the gabor kernel can hold
################################################################################

theta = deginrad(25)   # unit circle: left: -90 deg, right: 90 deg, straight: 0 deg
g_kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((6, 6), 10, theta, 5, 0, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)

img = cv2.imread('reference.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
filtered_img = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)

h, w = g_kernel.shape[:2]
g_kernel = cv2.resize(g_kernel, (3*w, 3*h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imshow('gabor kernel (resized)', g_kernel)

cv2.imwrite("reference_gabor.png", filtered_img)
```

Comment: If be independent with theta, it will not be gabor filter.

Comment: So I have to select the streets in the picture and then run the Gabor filter separately?

Comment: Then  what's your attention by using gabbor filter?

Comment: In my opinion, the Gabor filter is very suitable for detecting road markings.

Comment: This is by threshold, https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Y0b.png; This is by gabbor(maybe the parameters were set wrong) https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSUfb.png

Comment: Yes, and there you can see that the threshold does not eliminate interference. With the Gabor filter only the road markings are left, no kerbstones or other bright disturbing objects.